# Missing required structured data element

Tags: schema.org, google-search-console, microdata, amp-html, google-rich-snippets

In the Google search console it shows me under AMP:

Missing required structured data element for [this](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.usa-reisetipps.net%2Fnew-york-city%2Fmanhattan%2Fhigh-line%3Fhtml-amp%3D1#url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.usa-reisetipps.net%2Fnew-york-city%2Fmanhattan%2Fhigh-line%3Fhtml-amp%3D1)  site.

But I can't find any missing element. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After an [update](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6211453#amp-report) in the Search Console, the error is away.
This don't resolve my problem why this site has this error but it is not longer shown.
Thanks to all.

Answer (score 1):

The `BreadcrumbList` appears to be missing the image properties. You can check the required properties for `BreadcrumbList` [here](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/breadcrumbs) and `Article` [here](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/articles). I hope this helps.

Comment: All my other site use the same breadcrumpList and there are no errors.
And image for BreadcrumbList maybe a wrong documentation by google: See https://plus.google.com/u/0/+KenichiSuzuki/posts/LknZBxbVxtQ?cfem=1

Answer (score 0):

Te structured data seems to be good so the problem should be fixed **waiting for Google crawling again your pages**. The structured data may take up some time to [appear in Search Console](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2650907?hl=en):

> Even if the Structured Data Testing Tool shows no errors, it might
>   take some time until the page is re-crawled and re-processed for the
>   changes to be reflected in the Structured Data dashboard

Comment: This was my first idea. But this error is now still one month in the search console. Usaly after one-two days the console shows me fixed erros on other sites.

Comment: @Lovntola It can take longer than two days in some cases, try to [send](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6065812?hl=en) the url again to Google to speed up the process.

Comment: This code is still one month old. I tried resend several weeks ago.